# Smoothing inside the null-space of a partial differential operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, pseudo-differential-operators

Here is a fundamental question on PDEs whose answer must be known but is not easy to find:

Let $(Lu)(x) := \sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} c_\alpha(x)\partial_x^\alpha u(x)$ be a partial differential operator with boundedly smooth coefficients $c_\alpha\in C_b^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$. (Then $L:\mathcal D'(\Bbb R^n)\to\mathcal D'(\Bbb R^n)$ is well-defined and continuous.) Assume that $u\in W^{k,p}(\Bbb R^n)$ with $k\in\Bbb N$ and $1\leq p < \infty$ satisfies $Lu=0$. Does there exist for every $\epsilon>0$ such $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ that $\Vert u_\epsilon - u\Vert_{W^{k,p}(\Bbb R^n)}<\epsilon$ and $Lu_\epsilon=0$?

The constant coefficient case (at least with $p=2$) is very easy to obtain using frequency cutting, and my guess is that this idea generalizes. Thanks in advance for a reference or a proof sketch. (My knowledge of $\Psi DO$s is limited, but it would be enlightening to see if their basic theory is applicable here and if this result holds for them as well.)

Comment: Are you sure you want $u \in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?  For instance, if $L = - \Delta$ then the only solution to $L u =0$ that belongs to $W^{0,2}(\mathbb{R}^n) = L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is $0$.

Comment: For the Laplacian the result holds for trivial reasons even if I formulated my question with open $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ instead of $\Bbb R^n$. Of course I have a specific operator in mind, which has plenty of functions in its kernel regardless of what happens in the infinity, but its precise form is hardly of general interest.

Comment: You can't do what you're asking for even with the Laplacian in a bounded, open domain $U$.  Consider an arbitrary harmonic function $u$.  You're asking to approximate it by a harmonic function in $C^\infty_c(U)$, but there are no compactly supported harmonic functions.  This can be proved with the maximum principle, analyticity, or several other techniques.  This clearly generalizes to second order elliptic operators and basically any other operator that obeys a maximum principle (or has analytic solutions).

Comment: Oops. The lower index $c$ was not intentional. I meant $u_\epsilon\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ which is what one obtains with frequency cutting for the constant coefficient case. I will edit the original post to correct this.

Comment: Perhaps a proof for the constant coefficient case with $p=2$ is in place. In this situation $Lu=0$ if and only if $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m} c_\alpha (-i\xi)^\alpha \widehat u(\xi) = 0$. Let $J(\xi) = (1+|\xi|^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ and let $\chi_R$ be the characteritic function of $B(0,R)$. Then $\widehat u_R= \chi_R \widehat u$ satisfies $L u_R = 0$ and $u_R\in C^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ while $$\Vert u-u_R \Vert_{H^k(\Bbb R^n)}^2 = \Vert J^k(1-\chi_R)\widehat u \Vert_{L^2(\Bbb R^n)}^2 \to 0$$ as $R\to\infty$ by dominated convergence.

Comment: This $L^2$ special case is what I had in mind when I asked my first question.  I should have elaborated more then, but let me do so now.  In your calculation we find that $P(\xi) \hat{u}(\xi)=0$, which means that the support of $\hat{u}$ is contained in the set $\{P(\xi) =0\}$, which is of Lebesgue measure $0$.  Consequently, the solution you're approximating above is precisely $0$ to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this point. It seems that the question is vacuous when the behavior of $u$ is too restricted in the infinity. That is not, however, what I am really interested in. Replace $\Bbb R^n$ with more general open $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ and $C_b^\infty(\Bbb R^n)$ with $C^\infty(\overline U)$. Then, for example with $U\subset\Bbb R^2$ the unit square and $Lu=\partial_x u$, the kernel of $L$ contains plenty of non-smooth non-zero functions and the approximation result seems to hold. I am new at this site. Should I delete this question and repost it in this more meaningful form?